# Geth node sync even if it is not connected to any other geth node

Tags: go-ethereum, prysm, mastering-ethereum

I created a private network with five nodes. I am using geth and Prysm. When I remove the execution client node(example node5) using admin.removePeer(), the execution node disconnects from the network and shows peercount as zero. But the removed node still syncs with the network. How can I stop the removed node (node5) from syncing with the network?